# External/Internal webcam not working in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, ssd, webcam, cheese, uvc

first of all, it is not a hardware problem, they're working well with Windows 10.

And I don't have a Fn combination to activate webcam.

A month ago, I've moved Ubuntu to SSD drive I have. I could use webcam's before I move. I am not sure whether this moving may be the problem or not, anyway.

Running Cheese gives the error `Error during camera setup: No device found`

I've tried also running Guvcview and Depthsense's(my external webcam) interface but still I get errors like "no device found".

So I've checked out nearly all of similar questions in askubuntu, they've not help.

Here are my outputs that may show some clues:

sudo chmod 777 /dev/video*:

```
chmod: cannot access '/dev/video*': No such file or directory
```

lsusb:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 5986:026a Acer, Inc 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 045e:07a5 Microsoft Corp. Wireless Receiver 1461C
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 0b)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 0b)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI KT (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I218-LM (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev e4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5227 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 83)
```

Link for [lspci -k](http://web.itu.edu.tr/celenkah/lspcik.log) output

Link for [lsusb -v](http://web.itu.edu.tr/celenkah/lsusbv.log) output

Link for [dmesg](http://web.itu.edu.tr/celenkah/dmesg.log) output

Any help would make me happy.

Comment: You said that the webcam was working before, is it running 16.04 as well?

Comment: Yes. I've done a clean installation and it's running now, as well